# "The application “%@” can’t be opened." However doing "open with" and selecting default app works

Tags: applications

Using macOS Sierra, when I double click a file that is supposed to open with [Atom](https://atom.io/) I get this message:

[image]

However if I right click and choose the default option it works fine:

[image]

Comment: Try resetting the association. Get info on the file, set 'Open With' to Atom [even if it shows already, select it again from the drop menu] & then 'Change All...'

Comment: I tried that yesterday. Just tried changing the default app then swapping it back to atom. Problem is persisting

Comment: Then it might be time to rebuild the Launch Services database. [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) [freeware] can do that, from Maintenance tab/Rebuilding

Comment: You should post your update as an actual answer, not an edit to the question!

Comment: @grgarside I suppose, although it does not answer why this is happening

Comment: An onyx suggestion merits it's own answer... It's essentially a collection of common mac terminal commands. To rebuild the Launch Services it requires closing all programs, but before that it will do a hard drive check which will freeze access to the hard drive for a good bit. Not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Gave Onyx a shot, even after hitting cancel on the "Where is electron?" screen, it still fixed Atom!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by uninstalling atom (using appCleaner) and then reinstalling most recent version.

Comment: Yeah, Atom can be, well… annoying at times. It sometimes stores the ghost of a version and only leaves shortcuts to non existent files. The only way I have found to fix this is to delete and reinstall atom every once in a while. Hope they fix this soon!